# How can I make a proper graph from GTimeReport's google calendar excel file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, calendar, productivity, google-calendar

With GTimeReport, I downloaded a report of all my activities from google calendar in excel format.

The report looks like this:
[Example of GTimeReport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4MuS.jpg)

In the column 1 (see picture above) is a list of my calendar ("Sleep", "Hygiene", "Social" ect), and in the column 2 is the duration time of that event.

I would like to make a graph where I can see how much time I spent for each calendar. For example, I would like to see how much "Social" time I spent in the last month.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried making a graph or chart in Excel? Where did you run in to the problem? https://www.workzone.com/blog/how-to-make-a-graph-in-excel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** I evidently misunderstood your question the first time, so I've updated the data and graph below.  I've made the graph "dynamic", which means the graph will show the hours for the activity that is selected from a dropdown list.  Here is the data table and associated graph:

[image]

This formula, filled down from I2, lists the Dates for the last 30 days:

`=TODAY()-31+ROW(A1)`

And this formula, filled down from J2, lists the Times for the activity chosen from the dropdown:

`24*SUMIFS(C$1:C$126,A$1:A$126,I2,B$1:B$126,G$3)`

This formula assumes the Dates are in column A, Activities in column B, and Times in column C.  Change those references to suit your situation.

The graph is a "straight lined" Scatter graph (not a Line graph) and is made by selecting the data in columns I and J, and choosing "Straight Lined Scatter" from the Charts tab.

The title of the graph is also made dynamic by selecting it and typing `=G3` in the formula bar.

**Note:** There are several other considerations here, that are not specified in your question. If there are gaps in the data, for example, the time formula needs to be modified to handle that situation.

In any case, I hope this helps, and good luck.  If you found this useful, please click the check mark above to accept this answer.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me, but instead of your formula, I used the consolidation tool. However, what if I would like to make a line graph where I can see the progress/decay of one category? For example, I want to see in the last 30 days how many hours of sleep I got with a line chart. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Dario, are you near Modena? I have relatives there.

Comment: Hey, I'm from Naples, which is not so far to Modena, but I'm actually living in California. Anyway, thanks for the explanation. I really like this setup. Is it possible to have the excel file so I can replicate it? Thanks.

Comment: I visited Napoli once, years ago.  My relatives taught me to speak Napolitano.  Cazzo! :-). Here's the [spreadsheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wmipf9puu6cxt91/Calendar%20Graph.xlsx?dl=0).  Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Ahahaha, I hope you liked the city. You should go another time: it became cleaner and safer! Thanks again for the spreadsheet: I will try to figure out how you made the box that automatically select the activities with the relative time and develops the graph.